# Fastest way to find not null filed in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, isnull

I have sqlite table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [app_status](
[id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,
[status] TEXT DEFAULT NULL
)
```

This table is having multiple records like

```
1 "success"
2 NULL
```

where NULL is sqlite NULL

What is the fastest way to find out if table at-least one row where status `IS NOT NULL`?
Can I create some index or something else which I can use to count Not NULL fields ?

I have written  following query

```
SELECT 1 \
FROM [app_status]\
WHERE [status] IS NOT NULL
```

But it is taking 3 ms to 50 ms. I want to further optimize this time. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index on that column if it doesn't already have one, and/or limit your select.

```
select 1 from [app_status] where [status] is not null limit 1;
```

You don't need to go through the whole table if you're just checking if the column contains at least one non-null field.