# Optimizing sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Extending question 
[Fastest way to find not null filed in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484748/fastest-way-to-find-not-null-filed-in-sqlite/9484831#9484831)

I have table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [app_status](
[id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,
[status] TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
[type] INTEGER
)
```

Where type value either can be one or two. 
First I want to check if there is no row where type is equal to 1 and having status as not null.

It it fails I want to check if there is no row where type is equal to 2. 
For that I have written two sql query.

```
SELECT 1 
FROM [app_status]
WHERE [status] IS NOT NULL
AND [type]=1
```

if it doesn't return any row I fires

```
SELECT 2 
FROM [app_status]
WHERE [status] IS NOT NULL
AND [type]=2
```

Is there a way to merge these condition in one query. 
Returning one if any row having non null status and  type 1 if not returning 2 any row having not null status type 2.
otherwise returning 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
SELECT COALESCE(min(type), 0)
  FROM app_status
 WHERE status IS NOT NULL
   AND type IN (1,2)
```

?

Do you need all the duplicates?

Comment: @Vivek Goel: did you try the query? What do you expect and did it return the wrong result?

Comment: Benoit Should I create index on type to optimize it more ?

Comment: @Vivek Goel: I don't remember whether SQLite indexes index NULL values. If so, I would advise you to index status.